# SCSS compiled to CSS causing nested selectors errors

Tags: css, sass, compilation

I noticed when in using either VS code using the watch SASS `sass --watch assets/css/styles.scss assets/css/style.css`

1. nested scss class with "&" need to have a ","
2. nested css classes dont need "," just a whitespace

My browser shows that it suddenly flips upside down when i add a "," after the ampersand (&)

1. SCSS File

   .about{
   &__open**,**
   &__arrow {
   transform: rotate(-180deg);
   } }

Compiles to CSS

```
.skills__open**,** .skills__arrow {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

and the results in the css not working because CSS doesnt need ","

It would only work when i remove the "," after the ampersand (&), but that shouldnt be necessary cuz sass/scss usually needs a "," for nested selectors. Can someone explain why theres an issue with the compile?

Additionally however for other scenarios the "," after ampersand (&) compiles to css just fine but its just this one area in particular...

Heres the code and heres the preview of the error vs right one [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrcxO.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkMuQ.png)

NOTE: i am using css variables for the colors, and the rest i am using scss. Currently the stackoverflow only accepts css, therefore im putting scss code in a css file... It wont compile but just to reference

```js
/*==================== ACCORDION SKILLS ====================*/
const skillsContent = document.getElementsByClassName('skills__content'),
      skillsHeader = document.querySelectorAll('.skills__header')

function toggleSkills(){
    let itemClass = this.parentNode.className
    
    for(i = 0; i < skillsContent.length; i++){
        skillsContent[i].className = 'skills__content skills__close'
    }
    if(itemClass === 'skills__content skills__close'){
        this.parentNode.className = 'skills__content skills__open'
    }
}

skillsHeader.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', toggleSkills)
})
```

```css
:root {
--header-height: 3rem;

/*========== Colors ==========*/
/* Change favorite color */
--hue-color: 250; /*Purple 250 - Green 142 - Blue 230 - Pink 340*/

/* HSL color mode */
--first-color:hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%) ;
--first-color-second:hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%) ;
--first-color-alt:hsl(var(--hue-color), 57%, 53%) ;
--first-color-lighter: hsl(var(--hue-color), 92%, 85%) ;
--title-color:hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 15%) ;
--text-color:hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 45%) ;
--text-color-light:hsl(var(--hue-color),8%, 65%) ;
--input-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 70%, 96%) ;
--body-color:hsl(var(--hue-color), 60%, 99%) ;
--container-color:#FFF ;

/*========== Font and typography ==========*/
--body-font:'Poppins', sans-serif;

/* .5rem = 8px, 1rem = 16px, 1.5rem = 24px ... */
--big-font-size: 2rem;
--h1-font-size: 1.5rem;
--h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
--h3-font-size: 1.125rem;
--normal-font-size: .938rem;
--small-font-size: .813rem;
--smaller-font-size: .75rem;

/*========== Font weight ==========*/
--font-medium: 500;
--font-semi-bold: 600;

/*========== Margenes Bottom ==========*/
/* .25rem = 4px, .5rem = 8px, .75rem = 12px ... */
--mb-0-25: .25rem;
--mb-0-5: .5rem;
--mb-0-75: .75rem;
--mb-1: 1rem;
--mb-1-5: 1.5rem;
--mb-2: 2rem;
--mb-2-5: 2.5rem;
--mb-3: 3rem;

/*========== z index ==========*/
 --z-tooltip: 10;
--z-fixed: 100;
--z-modal: 1000;
}

/* Font size for large devices */
@media screen and (min-width: 968px) {
  :root {
--big-font-size: 3rem;
--h1-font-size: 2.25rem;
--h2-font-size: 1.5rem;
--h3-font-size: 1.25rem;
--normal-font-size: 1rem;
--small-font-size: .875rem;
--smaller-font-size: .813rem;
  }
}

/*==================== REUSABLE CSS CLASSES ====================*/
.section{
padding: 2rem 0 4rem;
}

.section__title{
font-size: var(--h1-font-size);
color: var(--title-color);
}

.section__subtitle{
font-size: var(--small-font-size);
display:block;
margin-bottom: var(--mb-3);
}

.section__title,
.section__subtitle{
text-align: center;
}

/*==================== LAYOUT ====================*/
.container{
max-width: 768px;
margin-left: var(--mb-1-5);
margin-right: var(--mb-1-5);
}

.grid{
display: grid;
gap: 1.5rem;
}

.header{
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: var(--z-fixed);
background-color: var(--body-color);
}
/*==================== SKILLS ====================*/

 .skills{
    &__container{
        row-gap:0;
    }

    &__header{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin-bottom: var(--mb-2-5);
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    &__icon
    &__arrow{
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    &__icon {
     margin-right: var(--mb-0-75);
    }

    &__title {
        font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
    }

    &__subtitle {
        font-size: var(--smaller-font-size);
        color: var(--text-color-light);
    }

    &__arrow {
        margin-left: auto;
        transition: .4s;
    }

    &__list {
        row-gap: 1.5rem;
        padding-left: 2.7rem;
    }

    &__titles {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      margin-bottom: var(--mb-0-5);
    }

    &__name {
      font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
      font-weight: var(--font-medium);
    }

    &__bar &__percentage {
      height: 5px;
      border-radius: .25rem;
    }

    &__bar {
      background-color: var(--first-color-lighter);
    }

    &__percentage {
      display: block;
      background-color: var(--first-color);
    }

    &__html {
    width: 90%;
    }

    &__css {
    width: 80%;
    }

    &__js {
    width: 60%;
    }

    &__react {
    width: 85%;
    }

    &__php {
    width: 80%;
    }

    &__node {
    width: 70%;
    }

    &__firebase {
    width: 90%;
    }

    &__python {
    width: 55%;
    }

    &__figma {
    width: 90%;
    }

    &__sketch {
    width: 85%;
    }

    &__photoshop {
    width: 85%;
    }

    &__close
    &__list {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    &__open
    &__list {
    height: max-content;
    margin-bottom: var(--mb-2-5);
    }

    &__open
    &__arrow {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--==================== UNICONS ====================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v3.0.6/css/line.css">

    <!--==================== SWIPER CSS====================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/swiper-bundle.min.css">

    <!--==================== CSS ==========-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

    <title>Responsive Portfolio Website</title>
</head>

<body>
<!--==================== SKILLS ====================-->
        <section class="skills section" id="skills">
            <h2 class="section__title">Skills</h2>
            <span class="section__subtitle">My technical level</span>

            <div class="skills__container container grid">
                <div>
                    <!--=============== SKILLS 1 ===============-->
                    <div class="skills__content skills__open">
                        <div class="skills__header">
                            <i class="uil uil-brackets-curly skills__icon"></i>

                            <div>
                                <h1 class="skills__title">Frontend developer</h1>
                                <span class="skills__subtitle"> 1 year</span>
                            </div>

                            <i class="uil uil-angle-down skills__arrow"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="skills__list grid">
                            <div class="skills__data">
                                <div class="skills__titles">
                                    <h3 class="skills__name">HTML</h3>
                                    <span class="skills__number">90%</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="skills__bar">
                                    <span class="skills__percentage skills__html"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="skills__data">
                                <div class="skills__titles">
                                    <h3 class="skills__name">CSS</h3>
                                    <span class="skills__number">80%</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="skills__bar">
                                    <span class="skills__percentage skills__css"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="skills__data">
                                <div class="skills__titles">
                                    <h3 class="skills__name">JavaScript</h3>
                                    <span class="skills__number">60%</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="skills__bar">
                                    <span class="skills__percentage skills__js"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="skills__data">
                                <div class="skills__titles">
                                    <h3 class="skills__name">React</h3>
                                    <span class="skills__number">85%</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="skills__bar">
                                    <span class="skills__percentage skills__react"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--=============== SKILLS 2 ===============-->
                    <div class="skills__content skills__close">
                        <div class="skills__header">
                            <i class="uil uil-server-network skills__icon"></i>

                            <div>
                                <h1 class="skills__title">Backend developer</h1>
                                <span class="skills__subtitle">More than 2 years</span>
                            </div>

                            <i class="uil uil-angle-down skills__arrow"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="skills__list grid">
                            <div class="skills__data">
                                <div class="skills__titles">
                                    <h3 class="skills__name">PHP</h3>
                                    <span class="skills__number">80%</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="skills__bar">
                                    <span class="skills__percentage skills__php"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="skills__data">
                                <div class="skills__titles">
                                    <h3 class="skills__name">Node Js</h3>
                                    <span class="skills__number">70%</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="skills__bar">
                                    <span class="skills__percentage skills__node"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="skills__data">
                                <div class="skills__titles">
                                    <h3 class="skills__name">Firebase</h3>
                                    <span class="skills__number">90%</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="skills__bar">
                                    <span class="skills__percentage skills__firebase"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="skills__data">
                                <div class="skills__titles">
                                    <h3 class="skills__name">Python</h3>
                                    <span class="skills__number">55%</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="skills__bar">
                                    <span class="skills__percentage skills__python"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <!--=============== SKILLS 3 ===============-->
                    <div class="skills__content skills__close">
                        <div class="skills__header">
                            <i class="uil uil-swatchbook skills__icon"></i>

                            <div>
                                <h1 class="skills__title">Designer</h1>
                                <span class="skills__subtitle">More than 5 years</span>
                            </div>

                            <i class="uil uil-angle-down skills__arrow"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="skills__list grid">
                            <div class="skills__data">
                                <div class="skills__titles">
                                    <h3 class="skills__name">Figma</h3>
                                    <span class="skills__number">90%</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="skills__bar">
                                    <span class="skills__percentage skills__figma"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="skills__data">
                                <div class="skills__titles">
                                    <h3 class="skills__name">Sketch</h3>
                                    <span class="skills__number">85%</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="skills__bar">
                                    <span class="skills__percentage skills__sketch"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="skills__data">
                                <div class="skills__titles">
                                    <h3 class="skills__name">Photoshop</h3>
                                    <span class="skills__number">85%</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="skills__bar">
                                    <span class="skills__percentage skills__photoshop"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
       </body>
      </html>
```